# AppLovin SDK Integration in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, sdk, applovin

How can I get SDK of Applovin for integrating into my Android Studio's project?
Whenever I download it from its official website, SDK downloads in `.tar` extension but I need to get jar file so I can place it in my libs folder.

Any helpful link or a way to integrate it?

Comment: .tar is an archive file format, meaning it can be unpacked into a directory. Have you tried that and looked if your desired .jar file is contained?

Comment: I solved my problem by a trick . I just changed the extension form tar to rar and I solved it . Thank you so much for your concern. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SDK comes in a `tar.bz` compressed file with the `JAR` inside.

Answer (score -2):

When you download the SDK is format tar.bz you need to extract and find the jar file inside.

Comment: I've removed the youtube link. Also, isn't this answer the same as the accepted one?